# How does Jade handle a src attribute? Why is it that /javascripts goes straight into the folder instead of /../public/javascripts?

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
        script(src="/javascripts/jquery-2.1.1.js")
        script(src="/javascripts/global.js")
    body
        block content
```

Apparently, `src="/../public/javascripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"` doesn't work, but `src="javascripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"` works

The file structure is like so:

```
nodetest
  public
    javascripts
      jquery-2.1.1.js
  views
    index.jade
```

Unless Jade actually creates index.html within the public folder? Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first jade doesn't actually save an index.html to disk, it generates it on the fly during the request response cycle

second, by default, express is set up to treat `public/` as the root directory for static files, so your reference to `/javascripts/jquery-2.1.1.js` points to `public/javascripts/jquery-2.1.1.js`

if you tried to load `/views/index.jade` or `/index.jade` it would 404 because Express won't find any matching static file

and finally `src="/javascripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"` (i.e. with a leading slash) should probably be how you reference it, because otherwise it's gonna look for child folders according to your url. (like, if you have `js/jquery.js` on the page `my.domain/parent/child.html`, the request would go to `my.domain/parent/js/jquery.js`